# Troubles to understanding notation and some terminology on cohomology of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, finite-groups

I am reading Adem, Milgram's book "Cohomology of finite groups" and I have some troubles with the notation. In particular, I don't get whether they are referring to the cohomology as a ring or as a group. For instance they denote by $H^{*}(G,M)$ for a $G$-module M, the cohomology group of $G$ with (untwisted) local coefficients in M. Whereas, other times they write $H^{*}(G,\mathbb{F}_{p})$ for the cohomology ring of $G$.

Also what's the difference between twisted and untwisted coefficients? And why when they are refering to cohomology ring they use only $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ or $\mathbb{F}$ (finite or infinite field) and they don't refer to the cohomology ring for arbitrary $G$-modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cohomology is a ring when you take untwisted coefficients in a ring. (Untwisted means the $G$ action is trivial.) As OmarAntolín-Camarena points out in the comments, you can still get a ring in the twisted case if the coefficients are a $G$-ring.

However, this does explain the terminology in your reference, since group cohomology with untwisted coefficients in a field is a ring, whereas for a general $G$-module, it is not a ring.

Comment: so, if I get you.. the cohomology becomes a ring if we have coefficients in a field right? and we do we have this distinction between twisted and untwisted? Why they have this name?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Because in the case that the action is nontrivial you don't have a ring structure. The notation comes from topology, where it's significantly harder to write down what "cohomology with twisted coefficients" is, the idea being that as you move around some space, your coefficients might turn around. (Like you might have $\Bbb Z$ coefficients at one point, loop around, and you'd have negated your coefficients... whatever that all means.)

Comment: @MikeMiller thank you for your response, if we have a topological space for instance, over a commutative ring then we have a ring structure on the cohomology. why this changes for the group cohomology?

Comment: It doesn't. In topological spaces, you're talking about cohomology with "untwisted coefficients". The reason you think that something is changed is that "twisted coefficients" in group cohomology are much more easily visible and earlier introduced, usually alongside the untwisted case.

Comment: @MikeMiller you helped me a lot, thank you. do you have any references about these things?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris: in the case of spaces, "twisted coefficients" are often called "local coefficients."

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip whilst in the case of groups this isn't true?

Comment: @mayer-vietoris: For groups, "twisted coefficients" corresponds to a non-trivial $G$-action. On spaces, twisted coefficients (or local coefficients) is a system of coefficients that varies over the space. It is a theorem that $H^*(G,M)=H^*(K(G,1),\mathcal M)$ where $\mathcal M$ is a certain local coefficent system.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip thank you for your response and excuse me for the consectuve questions. But do you know where can I find the latter that you have written please? I am talking about the isomorphism with the Eilenberg-MacLane space.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris It's stated without proof on p.13 (3.3) of these notes: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/papers/cohomology_hangzhou.pdf but I don't know a good reference (with proof) off the top of my head.

Comment: (1) Having the coefficients untwisted does not automatically make cohomology a ring, for $H^*(G;A)$ to have a ring structure you need a ring structure on $A$ itself.
(2) If $A$ is a $G$-ring, that is, if $A$ is a ring with an action of $G$ by ring homorphisms, then $H^*(G;A)$ get a ring structure even if the $G$ action is non-trivial.

Comment: @Omar Editing to reflect.